# Android: get cookie from header in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am creating new sample app with dagger, Rx, MVP and retrofit2. I am new in retrofit .For loginActivity i have send parameters as json string to web service.If the user exist and has permission, service return **true** in body and in header send Cookie:

```
D/Payesh: --> POST http://test.com/Authentication.svc/json/Login
D/Payesh: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
D/Payesh: Content-Length: 183
D/Payesh: {"username":"****","password":"***","customCredential":"****","isPersistent":false}
D/Payesh: --> END POST (183-byte body)
/data/data/com.groot.payesh/cache/okhttp_cache/journal.tmp
D/Payesh: <-- 200 OK http://test.com/Authentication.svc/json/Login (2111ms)
D/Payesh: Cache-Control: private
D/Payesh: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
D/Payesh: Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
D/Payesh: Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=3pi1nyrozbjwagw543Wsck4; path=/
D/Payesh: Set-Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=EA9127C4A3002F1D5EA5AADC279....; expires=Tue, 27-Mar-2018 15:17:22 GMT; path=/
D/Payesh: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGION
D/Payesh: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: test.com
D/Payesh: Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Accept
D/Payesh: Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
D/Payesh: Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
D/Payesh: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
D/Payesh: Date: Mon, 26 Mar 2018 15:17:22 GMT
D/Payesh: Content-Length: 4
D/Payesh: true
D/Payesh: <-- END HTTP (4-byte body)
```

this is my ApiService:

```
@POST(UrlManager.AUTHENTICATION+"Login")
Observable<String> getAuthentication(@Body RequestBody params);
```

this method return a string and i received **True** when i run my app an get user and pass. 
this is my observer method:

```
public DisposableObserver<String> observer() {
    return new DisposableObserver<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(String responseBody) {
            Log.i("--->", "onNext: " + responseBody);
        }...
```

I need this line in header:

> Set-Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=EA9127C4A3002F1D5EA5AADC279....; expires=Tue, 27-Mar-2018 15:17:22 GMT; path=/

this is my Interceptor that initialized with dagger from My **Application** Class:

```
@AppScope
@Provides
public HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger() {
        @Override
        public void log(String message) {
            Timber.d(message);
        }
    });
    return logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
}
```

How can i get **Set-Cookie** value?

Comment: Instead of Observable<String> return type in the interface, it will be Observable<Response<T>> //T being your data model. 
Then you can get response.headers. It's retrofit2.Response class.

Comment: @Debanjan server returned  just a String `true` in body.does it necessary to create a pojo class that has just one attribute as String class?

Comment: Yes. Since Response wraps around with the headers, the status of the request, success or failure, etc. You can just do Response<String>. Access the string through response.body

Comment: @Debanjan Then if i correct understand, i should change `Observable<String>` to `Observable<MyPojoClass>` to access to header. yes?

Comment: No, just do Observable<Response<String>>

Comment: @Debanjan , Ok dude, I will try and I'll announce you..

Comment: @Debanjan , thanks dude. it's work.